# Show todays article using Laravel 5 and Carbon

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm trying to show a daily article using Laravel 5 and carbon. I have converted the published_at string to a carbon object so I can get just the day to compare. I just can't figure out the where clause would be.

```
//this is in my model to make it a carbon object
protected $dates = ['published_at'];

//method in my controller
public function current()
{

    $article = Article::where('published_at', '>=', Carbon::now())->first();

    //testing prints 2 but today is the 1st
    dd($article->published_at->day);

    return view('articles.show')->with('article', $article);
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have a article with `published_at` tomorrow?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I have one for today and tomorrow. It seems like I would have to do an equal to day not the full Y-d-m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking if a timestamp is from today, the `DATE()` function comes in handy:

```php
$today = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
$article = Article::whereRaw('DATE(published_at) = ?', [$today])->first();
```

Comment: I get a type error when doing that: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereRaw() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: Interesting... What version of Laravel are you using? Anyways try `whereRaw('DATE(published_at) = ?', [$today])` instead

Comment: You're welcome. Apparently the method has been changed a bit. Earlier (even in 5.0) a single value was converted into an array by the query builder... Don't forget to accept the answer ;)